# Change strings in text file when the same number also occurs in another text file in bash

Tags: bash

I have two files with almost the same name in each line. The numbers define the uniqueness of each line in both text files. All numbers, which occur in `file1.txt` occur also in `file2.txt`. But not the other way around, meaning, that `file2.txt` has more strings. But `file2.txt` contains the correct names, which sometimes can be `OUT_P-[number]` or `OUT_D-B-CP-[number]`. Therefore I want to change the strings in `file1.txt` as they occur in `file2.txt`.
So:
I would like to leave lines in `file1.txt`, if exactly the same string occurs in `file2.txt`. But if there is the `OUT_P-[number]` in `file2.txt` with the same number as in `file1.txt`, then change the string in `file1.txt` to `OUT_P-[number]`. So for example: `file1.txt` has `OUT_D-B-CP-0001`, but `file2.txt` has `OUT_P-0001`, then change it also in `file1.txt`. And strings with numbers occuring only in `file2.txt` should be ignored and not added to `file1.txt`.

file1.txt:

```
OUT_D-B-CP-0001
OUT_D-B-CP-0002
OUT_D-B-CP-0005
OUT_D-B-CP-0007
OUT_D-B-CP-0008
OUT_D-B-CP-0009
OUT_D-B-CP-0014
OUT_D-B-CP-0022
OUT_D-B-CP-0024
OUT_D-B-CP-0025
OUT_D-B-CP-0027
OUT_D-B-CP-0032
OUT_D-B-CP-0038
OUT_D-B-CP-0246
OUT_D-B-CP-0249
OUT_D-B-CP-0250
OUT_D-B-CP-0260
```

file2.txt:

```
OUT_P-0001
OUT_P-0002
OUT_P-0005
OUT_P-0007
OUT_P-0008
OUT_D-B-CP-0009
OUT_P-0014
OUT_P-0022
OUT_P-0024
OUT_P-0025
OUT_D-B-CP-0026
OUT_P-0027
OUT_D-B-CP-0028
OUT_P-0032
OUT_P-0033
OUT_P-0038
OUT_D-B-CP-0057
OUT_D-B-CP-0085
OUT_D-B-CP-0087
OUT_D-B-CP-0121
OUT_D-B-CP-0178
OUT_P-0246
OUT_P-0249
OUT_P-0250
OUT_D-B-CP-0260
```

The output:

```
OUT_P-0001
OUT_P-0002
OUT_P-0005
OUT_P-0007
OUT_P-0008
OUT_D-B-CP-0009
OUT_P-0014
OUT_P-0022
OUT_P-0024
OUT_P-0025
OUT_P-0027
OUT_P-0032
OUT_P-0038
OUT_P-0246
OUT_P-0249
OUT_P-0250
OUT_D-B-CP-0260
```

I tried this: awk -F - 'NR == FNR { seen[$NF]; next } ($NF in seen)' file2.txt file1.txt > output.txt
I have no idea how to make this in bash, so can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**

Not a pure bash solution, but...
This one-liner command should do the trick. Tested on busybox awk.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=0}{s=$0; sub(/^[^0-9]+/,"",s); sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",$0); id[s]=$0; if(n<s+0)n=s+0} END {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {v=sprintf("%04d",i); if(id[v]!="") printf("%s%s\n",id[v],v) > "output.txt"}}' file1 file2
```

[Edit]

Or probably this what you want.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=0} NR==FNR {s=$0; sub(/^[^0-9]+/,"",s); sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",$0); id[s]=$0; if(n<s+0) n=s+0; next}{s=$0; sub(/^[^0-9]+/,"",s); sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",$0); if(id[s]!="") {id[s]=$0; if(n<s+0) n=s+0}} END {for(i=1;i<=n;++i) {v=sprintf("%04d",i); if(id[v]!="") printf("%s%s\n",id[v],v) > "output.txt"}}' file1 file2
```